# How to print the int value of an object inside another object array?

Tags: java, arrays, oop

How does one print the private int data field of an object that's within another object's array.

So if I had an object called Classroom and another object called Student, how would I print the student ID's of the student objects inside the Classroom object's private array member?

Would I override toString within Student to print the studentID? But how do you use that in the Classroom object's array to print out the array of IDs?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: You code the Classroom's toString method to include the ids of the students in th string that it returns.

Comment: @StephenC I wrote out a (override) toArray method which gives me the array of objects (so user doesn't have access to original array) but how would I override toString in the classroom class to print the array given to me by toArray itself? I wrote out getID in the student class as well.

Comment: *"how would I override toString in the classroom class to print the array given to me by toArray itself?* - You declare a method with the signature `String toString()`, and in the body of the method, you build and return a `String` that contains the IDs, separated by ... whatever you want.

Comment: @StephenC got it to work, thanks

Comment: So, did you solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, @StephenC  pointed me towards the right idea and after a bit of tinkering it worked out.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

In your `Student` class, you should create a method that returns the student's id, like in the example below:

```
class Student 
{
     private id;

     //... constructor and other code

     int getID() {return this.id;} 
}
```

In your `Classroom` class, you should create a method that adds the student to the array of students (I used an ArrayList in this case) and a method that prints the ids of all students in the list. Look below:

```
class Classroom
{
    private ArrayList<Student> studentsList;

    //... constructor and other code

    void addStudent(Student student) {
        this.studentsList.add(student);
    }

    void printStudentsList() {
        for(Student student: this.studentsList) {
            System.out.println(student.getID());
        }
    }
}
```

Note that it's just one of the ways you can use to achieve what you want. Since you didn't post your code, I improvised with the information you gave.

Comment: Your Classroom class does not have a student list but an integer list which is not what the question says.

Comment: That's true, thanks for pointing it out! I edited the answer to fix the code.

Answer (score 1):

class Student{
    private ArrayListids;

```
public Student(){

    ids.add("S001");

    ids.add("S002");

}

public ArrayList<String> getID(){

    return this.ids;

}
```

}
class ClassRoom {

```
public static void main(String args[]){

    Student s=new Student();

    ArrayList<String>studentID=s.getID();

    for(String id:studentID){

        System.out.println("Student ID :"+id);

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to SO! Code-only answers are discouraged because they don't provide any insight into how the problem was solved. Please update your answer to include an explanation of how your code solves the OP's problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to create some `public methods` to use the `private attributes`. I think you can design `Student` and `Classroom` class as following:

```
class Student
{
    private int studentID;
    //and others private attributes

    public student()
    {
       //write something here to initiate new object
    }
    public int getID()
    {
        return studentID;
    }
    //you can insert others methods here
}
class Classroom
{
   private Student[] studentArray;
   //add constructer here if you need it
   public int getStudentId(int position) //get student ID at `position` in the array
   {
     return studentArray[position].getID();
   }
}
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
       Classroom classroom = new Classroom();
       //do something to insert student to array of the `classroom`

       //assume you need to get ID of student in 6th place
       System.out.println(classroom.getStudentID(6));
    }
}
```